# Send email from Powershell based on SQL result

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Newbie. I have a flat file which I want to SQL-query for a string from within a PowerShell script (example SQL: `SELECT * FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]' WHERE Field1 LIKE '%LOGIN%'`), and if the query returns any rows the PS script should send an email. I'll have other functions to add later but right now I need to know how to pass the result to PS and send an email accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. What have you tried so far, and what errors/issues have you faced? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send mail from Sql Server itself, if DBMail is configured. The procedure `sp_send_dbmail` can send query results as an attachment. Like so,

```
declare @mailTo varchar(64) = 'valid@address.he.re';
declare @subj varchar(64) = 'Subject for message';
declare @fName varchar(64) = concat('QueryResults-', convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 120), '.txt');
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients = @mailTo,
@subject = @subj,
@query = N'select top(10) column1, column2 from [MyDatabase].[dbo].[SomeTable];',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = @fName;
```

The main limitation in this approach is that it will send you a piece of mail even if there are no results. To overcome this, consider, say, adding an `if` block. Like so,

```
declare @cnt int = 0;
set @cnt = (select count(column1) from table where <some conditions apply>);
if @cnt <> 0
begin
    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Invoke-SqlCmd2](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/Invoke-SqlCmd2) to check the table and then send mail with [Send-MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage).
If you want to write it yourself without using Invoke-SqlCmd2 you can do something like this:

```
$server   = 'localhost\sqlexpress'
$database = 'MyDB'
$query    = "SELECT * FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]' WHERE Field1 LIKE '%LOGIN%'"

$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$dataset = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet
$connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;Trusted_Connection=True;"
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$adapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command
$rowCount = $adapter.Fill($dataset)

if ($rowCount -gt 0) {
    Send-MailMessage ...
}
```

Fill in the details you need for Send-MailMessage in the end.